# String literal to char array literal

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I am writing some code which involves writing char arrays like so:

```c
char arr[] = { CONST1, CONST2, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };
```

(`CONST1` and `CONST2` are enum values)
Is there any way I can express this string of char literals, as a single string literal (via preprocessor macros or otherwise)? e.g.

```c
char arr = {CONST1, CONST2, "hello"};
```

Wrapping it in either single and double quotes produce compiler errors as expected.

Comment: Assuming `CONST1` and `CONST2` are define something like `'a'`, you can redefine them as `"a"` and then have simply `char arr[] = CONST1 CONST2 "hello";` (Note that it is not fully equivalent to your initial snippet - as that one lacks the null-termination)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Should have specified in the question - `CONST1` etc. are values from an enum, i.e. integers

Comment: Well, that would make things more complicated

Comment: It's not *essential* to my code, it would just make writing it (as this is a part that will change often over development) less of a chore, and it seemed strange that it was so laborious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your macro, use it wisely:

```
#define ENUM )(enum,
#define STR )(str,

#define MAKE_ARRAY(name, seq) \
    char name[END( MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_A(start, seq) )]; \
    char *MAKE_ARRAY_ptr = name; \
    END( MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_A(start, seq) ) \
    *MAKE_ARRAY_ptr = '\0';
    
#define CAT(x,y) CAT_(x,y)
#define CAT_(x,y) x##y

#define END(...) END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END

#define MAKE_ARRAY_ptr CAT(_MAKE_ARRAY_ptr_,__LINE__)

#define MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_start(x) 1
#define MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_enum(x) +1
#define MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_str(x) +sizeof(x)-1
#define MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_BODY(x,y) CAT(MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_,x)(y)
#define MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_A(...) MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_B
#define MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_B(...) MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_A
#define MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_A_END
#define MAKE_ARRAY_SIZEOF_LOOP_B_END

#define MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_start(x)
#define MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_enum(x) *MAKE_ARRAY_ptr++ = (char)x;
#define MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_str(x) for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(x)-1; i++) *MAKE_ARRAY_ptr++ = x[i];
#define MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_BODY(x,y) CAT(MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_,x)(y)
#define MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_A(...) MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_B
#define MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_B(...) MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_A
#define MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_A_END
#define MAKE_ARRAY_WRITE_LOOP_B_END
```

Usage:

```
enum E {e1, e2};

int main()
{
    MAKE_ARRAY(foo, ENUM e1 ENUM e2 STR "abc")
}
```

This expands to:

```
char foo[1 +1 +1 +sizeof("abc")-1];
char *_MAKE_ARRAY_ptr_42 = foo;
*_MAKE_ARRAY_ptr_42++ = (char)e1;
*_MAKE_ARRAY_ptr_42++ = (char)e2;
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof("abc")-1; i++)
    *_MAKE_ARRAY_ptr_42++ = "abc"[i];
*_MAKE_ARRAY_ptr_42 = '\0';
```

Here:

- `_MAKE_ARRAY_ptr_42` is a helper pointer. The number at the end comes from `__LINE__`, so you can't use two `MAKE_ARRAY`s at a single line. Replace it with a global variable if you want to.
- In `char foo[1 +1 +1 +sizeof("abc")-1];`:

  - `1` at the beginning is always there to make room for the null-terminator.
  - Two `+1`s come from `ENUM <name>`.
  - `+sizeof("abc")-1` comes from `STR "abc"`.
- `*_MAKE_ARRAY_ptr_42 = '\0';` at the end adds a null-terminator.

Comment: Ouch. I hope you don't intend to use it for real :) I would surely bash it in code review.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I've used worse in my pet projects. Yet to attempt it at work though. :P